# Is there a way to return just the name in a column that have True and False in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

`dataframee = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['ana','alex','paul','ana','alex','paul'], 'some_column': [False, False, False,True,True,False]})`

i want to return just the name ana and alex because they have True and False.

I'm doing something like this:

```
list_name = []
for i in dataframe['names']:
    if dataframe[dataframe['names'] == i].some_column.nunique() == 2:
        list_name.append(i)

list(set(list_name))
```

Is there another way more simple and more eficcient? Or return just the rows with names that have True and False in "some_column"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [1349]: a = dataframee.groupby('names')['some_column'].nunique() > 1
In [1351]: names = a.index[a].tolist()
In [1353]: names
Out[1351]: ['alex', 'ana']
```

Comment: The reason why I did not use nunique, due to we may have True, True, False .

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
g=df.groupby('names').some_column
s=g.sum().eq(1)&g.count().eq(2)
names
alex     True
ana      True
paul    False
Name: some_column, dtype: bool
s.index[s].tolist()
```